# how to reference to the django user model

Tags: django-models

hello i have a model named **Assigned_problem** in which a need to add two foreign keys of the model **user** in it. one foreign key represents the person who assigned the problem and the other foreign key represents the person to whom the problem is assigned. so in the course of updating the modifications done one the database structure i ave the following errors

*mini_url.Assigned_problem.assigned_to: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'Assigned_problem.assigned_to' clashes with reverse query name for 'Assigned_problem .assigned_by'.         HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Assigned_problem.assigned_to' or 'Assigned_problem.assigned_by'.*

THIS IS MY MODEL STRUCTURE

```
class Assigned_problem(models.Model):  
    assignation_status = models.IntegerField()  
    assigned_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, 
                                verbose_name="Assigned Date")  
    assigned_to = models.ForeignKey(User)  
    assigned_by = models.OneToOneField(User)  
    problem = models.OneToOneField('Problem')  
    def __str__(self):  
        return "{0}".'format'(self.problem.problem_content)
```

Comment: Did you try doing what the error message tells you to?

Answer (score 0):

With

```
assigned_to = models.ForeignKey(User)  
assigned_by = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

you declared two ForeignKeys to the model `User`. They're not distinguishable by their relation to `User` itself. Try to add a related_name attr for each of your foreign keys to `User`.

```
assigned_to = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="User assigned to")  
assigned_by = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="User assigned by")
```

See the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)